# Vslam ubuntu packages not installing

Tags: ros, vslam, ubuntu, rosdeb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to move from my Cturtle vslam installation to the diamondback version. After doing a sudo aptitude update and a sudo aptitude full-upgrade I try to install the ros-diamondback-vslam package however this fails because of different version dependencies:

```
koen@pma-09-031 ~ $ sudo aptitude install ros-diamondback-vslam 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
ros-diamondback-vslam{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 155MB of archives. After unpacking 357MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-diamondback-vslam: Depends: ros-diamondback-common-msgs (= 1.4.0-    s1298335197~maverick) but 1.4.0-s1299027564~maverick is installed.
                     Depends: ros-diamondback-driver-common (= 1.2.3-s1298335910~maverick) but 1.2.3-s1299028362~maverick is installed.
                     Depends: ros-diamondback-geometry (= 1.4.1-s1298335454~maverick) but 1.4.1-s1299027844~maverick is installed.
                     Depends: ros-diamondback-image-common (= 1.4.0-s1298338010~maverick) but 1.4.1-s1299029857~maverick is installed.
                     Depends: ros-diamondback-perception-pcl (= 0.9.0-s1298335998~maverick) but 0.10.0-s1299028482~maverick is installed.
                     Depends: ros-diamondback-ros (= 1.4.5-s1298334205~maverick) but 1.4.6-s1298587732~maverick is installed.
                     Depends: ros-diamondback-ros-comm (= 1.4.3-s1298334655~maverick) but 1.4.5-s1299027222~maverick is installed.
                     Depends: ros-diamondback-vision-opencv (= 1.4.1-s1298342629~maverick) but 1.4.1-s1299035380~maverick is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

 Keep the following packages at their current version:
 1)     ros-diamondback-vslam [Not Installed]              

 Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n

 *** No more solutions available ***

 The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

 Keep the following packages at their current version:
 1)     ros-diamondback-vslam [Not Installed]              

 Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] q
 Abandoning all efforts to resolve these dependencies.
 Abort.
```

Is this caused by a problem in the package generation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9419/vslam-ubuntu-packages-not-installing/) by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

vslam is currently broken, so the debian packages are not available for diamondback.  You will have to install from source if you wish to use it.  In general, experimental/research stacks may often go into a broken state, at which point their debian packages will be pulled.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-03-16**:
The debian build status pages http://www.ros.org/wiki/release will give you information about what is in the repository.  Pre-1.0 stacks should be considered volatile and will be pulled if broke.  Stack owners are generally aware when their stacks are pulled, so there is no need to file a ticket.

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-03-15**:
Is there a protocol to notify such broken debian packages? Or do I file a ticket each time?